# All my sent mail is marked as spam

Tags: email, postfix-mta, spam, digital-ocean, system-administration

I've configured Postfix and Dovecot in my server (in this server I've my website and my mailserver), but if I send an email, it is marked as spam! I've also configured DKIM!!

So, here some information:

```
$ host MYDOMAIN.COM
MYDOMAIN.COM has address 178.62.48.51
MYDOMAIN.COM mail is handled by 50 mail.MYDOMAIN.COM.
```

My posfix main.cf:

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no
append_dot_mydomain = no
readme_directory = no
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/mailcert.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/mail.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_tls_security_level=may
smtpd_tls_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3
local_recipient_maps = proxy:unix:passwd.byname $alias_maps
myhostname = mail.MYDOMAIN.COM
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = mail.MYDOMAIN.COM, MYDOMAIN.COM, localhost, localhost.localdomain
relayhost = 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
virtual_alias_domains = MYDOMAIN.COM
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
milter_protocol = 2
milter_default_action = accept
smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:12301
non_smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:12301
```

My postfix master.cf:

```
smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
pickup    fifo  n       -       -       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       -       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      fifo  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       -       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       -       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce

verify    unix  -       -       -       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       -       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
showq     unix  n       -       -       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error

retry     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       -       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       -       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       -       -       1       scache
maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}

uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix  -   n   n   -   2   pipe
  flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py

  ${nexthop} ${user}
submission inet n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=no
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
  -o smtpd_sasl_type=dovecot
  -o smtpd_sasl_path=private/auth
```

My /etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   MYDOMAIN MYDOMAIN

::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

My /etc/hostname:

```
MYDOMAIN
```

My /etc/mailname:

```
MYDOMAIN.COM
```

I can't explain why email goes in spam, any suggestion?

I underline that in the code I've used my real domain. I also underline that in some file (like hostname) I've used the domain whitout the TLD but I don't know if it is right (example: I've used DOMAIN instead DOMAIN.COM).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IP address you gave in your comment, indeed owned by DigitalOcean, does appear clean to me w.r.t. [DNSBLs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNSBL) like [SpamHaus](http://www.spamhaus.org/lookup/) and IP reputation sites like [SenderBase](http://www.senderbase.org/).  That said, DigitalOcean certainly has a [bad reputation](https://duckduckgo.com/digital.ocean%20spam) when it comes to controlling its customers' outbound spam and perhaps some filter is over-aggressive against broad DigitalOcean IP ranges.

I did notice that the domain in your IP's [rDNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup) happens to lack an MX record.  Lots of anti-spam systems will reject mail from you in this scenario, especially if that's the domain you actually send from.  You appear to have covered the rest of [FCrDNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward-confirmed_reverse_DNS), which I assume is also reflected by your HELO.

(I've omitted references to your actual IP or domain in the event you wanted to retract the IP from your question.)